# How to autohide stalonetray?

Tags: xmonad, tray

I'm using `stalonetray` to hold `nm-applet`. Is there a way to hide it after a wifi network is selected?

Or maybe with key bindings?

(ubuntu + xmonad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `stalonetray` and `nm-applet` to select a wifi network. You can list wifi networks on the command line using `nmcli dev wifi` and connect to a network using `nmcli dev wifi connect SSID password PASSWORD`.

Or you could set up keybindings to start the tray using `stalonetray` and stop it using `killall stalonetray`. The applet can cope with it.

Comment: Good point for suggesting `nmcli`! Is there a way to sort the WiFi by SIGNAL?

Comment: I don't think so, would make a good suggestion for upstream. Or you could write your own utility using e.g. Python and gobject-introspection.

Comment: `nmcli dev wifi | sort -k6r` will work. Thank you very much for your insight answer.